# Find occurrences of length of words in array

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences length in array;

Here's what I've tried, but I don't know what to do after.

```
function instances_and_count($input) {
    $arr = explode(' ', $input);
    $count = 0;
    $test = [];
    foreach ($arr as $arr_str) {
        if ($count != 0) {
            $test = [$count => 'hi'];
            print_r($test);
        }
        $count++;
    }
}

$test = 'A heard you say something I know you ain\'t trying to take me homeboy.';
instances_and_count($test);
```

In this example, I explode a string to make an array. I need a count of let's say all words with a length of 1 which in this string it's a count of 2 (A and I); How can I do this for all lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's array functions are really useful here; we can convert our [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)d array of strings to an array of string lengths using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), and then use [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count how many words of each length there are:

```
$test = 'A heard you say something I know you ain\'t trying to take me homeboy.';

$counts = array_count_values(array_map('strlen', explode(' ', $test)));
print_r($counts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [9] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [6] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [8] => 1
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ebda8)

Note that there is a length of 8 in this array for the "word" `homeboy.` This can be avoided either by stripping trailing punctuation from the string, or (better) using [`str_word_count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to extract only whole words from the original string. For example (thanks @mickmackusa):

```
$test = 'I heard you say something I know you ain\'t trying to take me homeboy.';

$counts = array_count_values(array_map('strlen', str_word_count($test, 1)));
print_r($counts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [9] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [6] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [7] => 1
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZAqLL)

If you want to output the array with keys in order, just use [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) on it first:

```
ksort($counts);
print_r($counts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
)
```

This is not necessary for use within your application.

Comment: We should be seeing the more concise version here -- `array_map('strlen',...)`  ...and potentially `str_word_count()`?

Comment: @mickmackusa been a while since I wrote this answer so not sure why I did it the way I did, perhaps I originally had more in the function that just `strlen`. Anyway, you are definitely right on that and I've edited the answer. As for `str_word_count`, I'm not sure how you would apply that to this?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/ZAqLL the only advantage is that it removes the punctuation.

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah, that is a good point, you can definitely argue that the "word" `homeboy.` should only have 7 letters, not 8. I've updated the answer using your code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the length of the word as array key. For each word you are looping over, check if an array entry for that length already exists - if so, increase the value by one, otherwise initialize it with 1 at that point:

```
function instances_and_count($input) {
  $words = explode(' ', $input);
  $wordLengthCount = [];
  foreach($words as $word) {
    $length = strlen($word);
    if(isset($wordLengthCount[$length])) {
      $wordLengthCount[$length] += 1;
    }
    else {
      $wordLengthCount[$length] = 1;
    }
  }
  ksort($wordLengthCount);
  return $wordLengthCount;
}
```

Result:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 3
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 2
  6 => int 1
  8 => int 1
  9 => int 1
```